# Form submission not executing on an Ajax success page

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am using Ajax to display some content inside a form in my page that have an `id` of `display` as below

```
<form method="post"><div id="display"></div></form>
```

In the content that displayed by `Ajax`, there is a button named `assign`. I am using php to check if form submitted and if it is, then it will redirect to another page as below

```
if(isset($_POST['assign'])){
        header("Location: trial.php");
    }
```

But somehow it is not going to that page. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

**Edit 1**

More explanation. From main page, using `Ajax`, I am directing to a php page where it `echo` some information including `echo` a button to main page. Those information will be showed in the main page in the `display` id. But when I press the button, form is not submitting

Comment: This is too less information. Please post what you tried.

Comment: I tried to explain further. Please let me know if it is not clear or if you need further info

Comment: Well you have no action tag in the form that you posted.

Comment: But I am using php `$_POST` method to check if the form submitted in the same page. Doing that way don't need to have action tag right?

Comment: $_POST Valiable holds the content of that field. If you submit a form you need to tell the form where to...

Comment: Check dearsinas answer. It should help you track it down

Answer (score 2):

That's not how AJAX works.

- Open up the developer console (`F12` in Chrome).
- Click on the `Network` tab on top.
- Click on your `Assign` button.
- Find the row that was created when you pressed the button.
- Click on the row, then click on the on the `Response` tab.

Do you see the HTML data you were expecting? If you want an AJAX response to change your current browser URL, you'll need to instead "send back" to the web page a response that tells your JS that it should force a URL change.